# Java - delay between events after entering the value into JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, delay, jtextarea, event-dispatch-thread

I prepared a simple form (javax.swing.JFrame) on which JTextArea is located. 
After entering the "TAB" value, I would like to see a visible JPanel on the form for a few seconds. Unfortunately, when I have the following events:

```
 <br>
JPanel.setVisible (true); <br>
TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep (3); <br>
JPanel.setVisible (false); <br>
in keyPressed for JTextArea.KeyListener ()
```

they don't execute one after another - first I get sleep, then JPanel.setVisible (true) and JPanel.setVisible (false)

```
public class Form1 extends JFrame {

    JTextArea txt1 = new JTextArea();
    JPanel pnl2 = new JPanel();

    public Form1() {

        txt1.setLocation(10, 10);
        txt1.setSize(100, 30);
        txt1.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e
            ) {
                if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_TAB) {
                    e.consume();

                    pnl2.setVisible(true);
                    try {
                        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(3);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(Form1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                    pnl2.setVisible(false);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e
            ) {
            }
        });
        add(txt1);

        pnl2.setLayout(null);
        pnl2.setLocation(10, 150);
        pnl2.setSize(100, 100);
        pnl2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder());
        pnl2.setVisible(false);
        add(pnl2);
    }
}
```

Main class:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Form1 f = new Form1()
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setSize(500, 400);
                f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                f.setResizable(false);
                f.setLayout(null);
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        }
        );
    }
}
```

How can I get the effect of showing the panel on the form for a few seconds after entering the "TAB" button on TextArea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't block the AWT Event Dispatch Thread (EDT).

Instead, set a `javax.swing.Timer` (get the package right - not the other one!). The Swing `Timer` may create another thread to do the timing, but posts the event back through the EDT (via `java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater` or similar). The code executed after the `sleep` should be move to an action listener.

```
                pnl2.setVisible(true);
                javax.swing.Timer timer =
                    new javax.swing.Timer(3000, event -> {
                        pnl2.setVisible(false);
                    });
                timer.setRepeats(false);
                timer.start();
```

(I have used the fully qualified name to emphasize the right `Timer`. Sometimes I forget that by default it will repeat, which would be confusing.)